# When running a wagtail migrate why do I get a postgresql error?

Tags: django, wagtail

I'm trying to setup a development environment on my Windows 10 machine for a wagtail site. I'm using wagtail 2.6.3 and postgresql 12. I'm getting this error when I try to migrate the first setup.

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "WITH ORDINALITY"
```

Below is my requirments.txt

```
beautifulsoup4==4.6.0
chardet==3.0.4
Django==2.2.13
django-modelcluster==4.4.1
django-taggit==0.24.0
django-treebeard==4.3.1
djangorestframework==3.11.0
draftjs-exporter==2.1.7
html5lib==1.0.1
idna==2.9
Pillow==6.2.2
pytz==2020.1
requests==2.23.0
six==1.15.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
Unidecode==1.1.1
urllib3==1.25.9
wagtail==2.6.3
webencodings==0.5.1
Willow==1.1
wincertstore==0.2
```

I have also tried doing a completely new app using the basic wagtail installation instructions. When I use postgresql I get errors in migrate. I have other django apps running on this machine.

I've also installed a django app and the migrate worked, so it has something to do with wagtail migration issues.

Comment: It might be helpful to add a bit more information, is this is a new project from scratch or checking out an existing project? What version of Python are you running, what is the full stack trace error you are getting and when does this error throw? Do you have existing migrations, also have you run `python manage.py makemigrations` and then `python manage.py migrate`.

Comment: I've tried creating a new wagtail app and running migrate and I get the errors. I have tried to reinstall postgres using 11 and I still get the error. It seems to have something to do with django utils.